# How convert dos datetime to Unix time?

Tags: java, time

Unix time is number seconds from beginning 1970 year. Java File time is number of milliseconds from 1970. Both Greenwich timezone. But dos datetime is bitfield format, several bits to day, month, year and time hh,mm,ss, local Timezone. Converting Unix time to File time is easy - mul. 1000. Converting from Dos datetime to Unix is difficult. 
Archive library UnAceV2 has Dos datetime format. How convert it to Unix?

Answer (score 3):

Look at source of `java.util.zip.ZipEntry.dosToJavaTime(long)` and `java.util.zip.ZipEntry.javaToDosTime(long)`

Answer (score 2):

```
    /** Converts DOS time to Java time (number of milliseconds since epoch). */
    private long dosToJavaTime(long dosTime) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int) ((dosTime >> 25) & 0x7f) + 1980);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, (int) ((dosTime >> 21) & 0x0f) - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, (int) (dosTime >> 16) & 0x1f);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) (dosTime >> 11) & 0x1f);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) (dosTime >> 5) & 0x3f);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, (int) (dosTime << 1) & 0x3e);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime().getTime();
    }
```